# Using brackets/parantheses inside shell scripts vs using them from the command line bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I use `rm -r secrets/!(snapsearch)` on the command line. It works and deletes everything in the secrets folder except for snapsearch folder.

However when I use the exact same command in a bash script and execute it, it complains about the parentheses.

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why does it work from the command line, and not from the bash script?  And how can I make this work from the bash script?

Comment: Did you try escaping them? `\(snapsearch\)`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either. It returns `rm: cannot remove ‘secrets/!(snapsearch)’: No such file or directory` It certainly does exist! And when running from CLI is works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `extglob` in non-interactive mode, i.e. when executing your script.

You have two options.  First, add the following line to the top of your script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Note that since `extglob` changes the way in which expressions are parsed, so it needs to be on a separate line by itself and cannot be a part of a block, e.g. a `if` block.

Second, execute the script by saying:

```
bash -O extglob scriptname
```

(The second option wouldn't require changes to the script.)

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You wouldn't need to perform any sort of escaping if you do either of the two.

Comment: It works when it's not in a if block. But once I put in an IF block, it still complains about the parentheses. I'm using the `shopt -s extglob`. Basically the `shopt -s extglob` cannot be inside the IF block. It needs to be outside.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That's correct.  `shopt -s extglob` can't be inside a `if` block.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `shopt` changes the way in which expressions are parsed by the shell and it needs to be on a line by itself and not within a block.